# OptaPlanner nurse rostering

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

Discovered OptaPlanner whilst working on a roster generator for a hospital in Malawi, and it would be a perfect fit for the problem.  So some newbie questions:

1) I can't see a way to easily enter holidays (apart from multiple day off requests), can see how to add this but don't wish to reinvent the wheel.

2) I can't see a way to add a constraint giving nurses a day off before and 2 days off after a night shift (there are just two shifts, day and night) any suggestions gratefully received, not sure where to start on this one.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of adding or editing score rules in [the DRL file](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl#L88). For some of them, you'll need to expand [the domain model](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/domain) to include extra information (such as holiday start/end etc) and also adjust the XML dataset to include that information.

1) Add a HolidayRequest domain object and do something like this (warning: pseudo code):

```
rule "holidayRequest"
    when
        $holidayRequest : HolidayRequest($employee : employee, $startShiftDate : startShiftDate, $endShiftDate : startShiftDate, $weight : weight)
        $assignment : ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shiftDate >= $startShiftDate, shiftDate <= $endShiftDate)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $weight); // Maybe you want it hard instead of soft?
end
```

2) I'd rephrase that as (very very pseudo code)

```
ShiftAssignment(type = DAY, $date)  
ShiftAssignment(type = NIGHT, date = $date + 1)
```

And also don't have this

```
ShiftAssignment(type = NIGHT, $date)  
ShiftAssignment(type = DAY, date = $date + 1)
```

or this:

```
ShiftAssignment(type = NIGHT, $date)  
ShiftAssignment(type = DAY, date = $date + 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - my current plan to use DayOff requests didn't work particularly well (I wrote a small routing to generate the XML required) - but various days would be rostered in during a holiday (need to be a hard constraint - but how to specify in XML)  Need to read up some more to work with the night/day problem too.

Comment: Strangely - in the drl file there is the comment:                    // Two free days after a night shift
// TODO

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using patterns?  - Disallow DayNight, NightDay and NightOffDay ?